# Detection of local directory access listing on Mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, inotify

I have a problem when I detect accessing folder on Mac in python programming.
I use [Pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify), watchdog, fsevent to monitor files change, it's very good, but now I need to detect when I access into a folder. I want to know when someone opens up the Finder at a folder so I can check for changes to that folder only
Ex: I'm currently in here **folder/**
and when I go to **folder/folder_children** , my python program can know that.

Anyone know how to detect it?

Comment: This is not available, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @BurhanKhalid for your quick reply.I see filezilla has the toggles processing of transfer queue, when I go to a folder in local (left window), I go to a folder in server too (right window). It maybe the same with what I need.

Comment: That's because in FileZilla, they are using their own file browser, so they can detect such things. For your case, you'll have to write your own version of 'Finder' to do the same.  The system 'Finder' will not provide you this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use Watchman.  We provide a (not currently very well documented) python client and it works on Linux and Mac (and Solaris and FreeBSD)

https://facebook.github.io/watchman/

For your use case, the following aspects of Watchman are pertinent:

- Watchman builds a time ordered index of file changes
- Each logical change has an associated "clock" value
- You can query Watchman for the list of files that changed since a clock value
- For convenience you can ask Watchman to track a clock value with a symbolic name; we call these named cursors

For example:

When I run `watchman since /path/to/dir n:myclient` the first time, I get a complete list of files in `/path/to/dir`.  When I run it the second and subsequent times it returns the list of files that changed since the last time it was run.

You can construct more sophisticated queries than `since` to match certain files; pertinent docs:

- https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cmd/since.html
- https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cmd/query.html

Architecturally:

- On the remote side, run the Watchman service and ask it to monitor the root of the filesystem tree that you're syncing.  Watchman always watches recursively.
- On the client side, you can periodically (or via whatever heuristic you use to figure out when is appropriate) call up to the server
- When polled by the client, the server issues a since query to Watchman using a cursor name
- Your server only needs to re-examine the files in that list

You can use a separate cursor name per discrete client if you have multiple clients to synchronize.

Comment: thanks you Wez Furlong (@ seem have a problem). We have a sync program like dropbox.
So we have to rescan server in regularly time (rescan all folders/files into root folder). It's suck and slow, so we want to detect when user open a local folder and we will scan for changes to that folder only (not all into root folders) on server, it will improve the performance.
So I'm trying to detect when user access to local folder.

Comment: Ack. Updated my answer; happy to expand on it some more if needed, just let me know!